# How can I update IIS 10 v1607 to IIS 10 v1809 on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

I am tasked with updating IIS 10 v1607 to IIS 10 v1809 on Windows Server 2016. I know v1809 comes installed with Windows Server 2019, but I can't upgrade to 2019.

How can I update IIS 10 v1607 to IIS 10 v1809 on Windows Server 2016? Can this be done?

Comment: `I am tasked with updating IIS`? Why?

Comment: One thing you should learn is that cross posting to both Stack Overflow/Server Fault won't give you more assistance (but maybe more downvotes).

Comment: @LexLi I wanted to close the question on StackOverflow but the only thing I could do was vote to close it. Yeah, I can't close my own question, I can just "vote" to close it.

Comment: @GregAskew Because the client got it in their head that they should update every system before the end of the year. I tried telling them this isn't possible without updating the OS, but they wouldn't have it. Since I can't find any reference on the "great" MSDN website for HOW to update IIS or that IIS is locked to the Windows version, I thought I should ask here.

Comment: @LexLi you mentioned on the other question, which I since deleted, that "if you cannot upgrade the OS itself, you cannot upgrade IIS either". I know this, but I can't find a reference from any official source. Can you provide one? Also, it's the client's time that is wasted. I get paid either way, so I don't really care.

Comment: @user1969903: This isn't a good forum for random busy work tasks that have no basis. Also, no-one shows up at the end of November saying "we have to update every system before the end of the year". That is literally the opposite of what this forum is for, and you don't need this forum to do that.

Comment: They do show up saying just that when they have budget to spend until the end of the year, otherwise they get less budget to spend the following year. Do you think I have nothing better to do with my time then ask questions for the sake of asking questions? In any case, do you have an answer? Otherwise, you're not helping. If this isn't a forum, why the **** do people like you come out of the woodwork to argue just like they do on forums? Don't like the question? Downvote, leave a comment explaining why if you have the decency, and move on.

Comment: You simply cannot expect everything to be documented. Ever since IIS became an OS component (IIS 5 at least, and two decades ago) what I commented has been de facto.

Comment: BTW, I wonder if you can simply delete a question. Why should you ever close your answer when clearly it should be deleted.

Comment: @LexLi I know you're right, but some sort of documentation would've helped me get the point across to the client.

Comment: @LexLi  As for the question, I realized I asked it in the wrong place, so I wanted to close it because when doing so you get asked why and you have the option to select that the question is more appropriate for a different stack exchange website, whereas deleting the question doesn't give me the chance to explain why I deleted it. I obviously misunderstood the purpose of the close functionality, which is for other users. This begs the question of why I have the option to vote on closing my own question, but I don't think this is something to be discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

SUGGESTION:

1. Review all the Windows updates for your client's Windows Server 2016 install.
2. See if there are any IIS updates in the list.
3. Explain to your client that the only "IIS download" available from Microsoft is "IIS Express" - and they don't want that.  If IIS 10 v1809 isn't available as a Windows Update for your version of Windows Server ... then it simply isn't available ... without updating Windows Server itself.

'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can not upgrade 'just' IIS as it is a builtin role of the windows server release you are using.